# modify json file using cJSON library

Tags: cjson

what i want to do is reading a json format file and modify it then writing the modified content to file.

```
 55     cJSON *root,*basicpara;
 56     char *out;
 57 
 58     root = dofile("basicparameter.cfg");
 59     out = cJSON_Print(root);
 60     printf("before modify:%s\n",out);
 61     free(out);
 62     basicpara = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"basicparameter");
 63     cJSON_GetObjectItem(basicpara,"mode")->valueint = 0;
 64     cJSON_GetObjectItem(basicpara,"TimeoutPoweron")->valueint = 10;
 65 
 66     out = cJSON_Print(root);
 67     printf("after modify:%s\n",out);
 68     free(out);
 69     //write_file("basicparameter.cfg",out);
 70     cJSON_Delete(root);
```

i am confused why both contents are the same...

```
before modify:{
    "basicparameter":   {
        "mode": 1,
        "nBefore":  2,
        "nAfter":   2,
        "LuxAutoOn":    50,
        "LuxAutoOff":   16,
        "TimeoutPoweron":   30
    }
}
after modify:{
    "basicparameter":   {
        "mode": 1,
        "nBefore":  2,
        "nAfter":   2,
        "LuxAutoOn":    50,
        "LuxAutoOff":   16,
        "TimeoutPoweron":   30
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a old question but can you tell me how you are actually reading your JSON files content. What is dofile function, what kind of file is basicparameter.cfg?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `cJSON_SetNumberValue` macro for setting the number. The problem is, that you are only setting the `valueint` property but printing relies on the `valuedouble` property.

Having both `valueint` and `valuedouble` in cJSON was a terrible design decision and will probably confuse many people in the future as well.